# Error pulling tkinter entry widget string

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am in the process of making a GUI to control a GPIO function I created that just makes a couple lights blink. For the time being it just makes two LED's blink simultaneously with a user inputted delay and a user inputted number of loops using tkinter's Entry widget. This is where my problem arises, when I try to pull the inputs from the Entry widget's I get a 'str' error, which makes sense because I assume the entry is of the string data type and my blink function must be looking for an integer data type? However, if I force this to be an integer I then get an "invalid for literal int() base 10" error prompt. Please help.

Here is my current script:

Disclaimer: There may be some syntax errors. The firewall at Deere doesn't allow me to connect to the network so I had to type all of this again.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("LED Controller")
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)

CycleLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Cycles", font="Verdana 12 bold")
CycleLabel.grid(row=1,column=1)
CycleInput = tk.Entry(root)
CycleInput.grid(row=1,column=2)
CycleInput.focus_set()
cycle=CycleInput.get()

SpeedLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Speed", font="Verdana 12 bold")
SpeedLabel.grid(row=1,column=1)
SpeedInput = tk.Entry(root)
SpeedInput.grid(row=2,column=2)
SpeedInput.focus_set()
speed = SpeedInput.get()

def callback():
    print (CycleInput.get())
    print (SpeedInput.get())

def Blink(cycle,speed):
    for platypus in range (0, cycle):           ** This is the line that the error always points to. 
        print("Loop" + str(platypus+1))
        GPIO.output(7,True)
        GPIO.output(11, True)
        time.sleep(speed)
        GPIO.output(7, False)
        GPIO.output(11, False)
        time.sleep(speed)
        print("Done")

ButtonFrame = tk.Frame(root)
ButtonFrame.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan=3)

B2 = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text="Start", width=10, command=lambda:Blink(cycle,speed), font="Verdana 10 bold")
B2.grid(row=3,column=2)

B1 = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text"Print Inputs", width=10, command=callback, font="Verdana 10 bold")
B1.grid(row=3,column=1)

def clear():
    CycleInput.delete(0, 'end')
    SpeedInput.delete(0, 'end')

B3 = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text="Clear", width=10, command=clear, font="Verdana 10 bold")
B3.grid(row=3,column=3)

CloseFrame = tk.Frame(root)
CloseFrame.grid(row=4, column=1, columnsapn=3)

B4 = tk.Button(CloseFrame, text="Close", width=20, command=root.destroy, font="Verdana 10 bold", activebackground='red')
B4.grid(row=4,column=2)
```

Comment: Have you searched for an answer? Your question doesn't show any signs of research. I suggest you start by searching for `[tkinter] gpio`. At the time I write this there are 58 questions, some of which are probably very similar to this question.

Comment: My question doesn't even involve the GPIO.

Comment: Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Tried this but it gives me another error of self not defined: 
 
self.y = tk.StringVar()
SpeedInput = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = self.y)
speed = int(self.y.get())

Comment: Right. `self` only applies when using classes, which you are not.

Comment: First experience with programming and I have learned this much from Youtube and forums. So I am sorry if I'm bothering you. I must look like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
command=lambda:Blink(cycle,speed)
```

Your `cycle` and `speed` variables were set exactly once, immediately after creating the corresponding Entry fields.  They are therefore always going to be empty strings; the user had no chance at all to enter a value for them.  You need to need to do the `.get()`s *after the button has been clicked* - either in this lambda, or in `Blink` itself.

You also need to convert the entered strings to ints, and handle the possibility that the entered strings weren't valid ints.